# The best resources to read in English "in" Vs "on"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, sentence-construction

I want to write about the best websites and apps for reading in English, but I am not sure whether I put on or in, in my example below:

"I want to share the best resources to read in English  in/on."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They mean different things.

Resources **in** English are in the English language.

Resources **on** English are **about** the English language.

Comment: That means " I want to share the best resources to read in English on" is the correct one?

Comment: If the resources are both **in** English and **about** English you could say "I want to share the best resources on English, in English" or "I want to share the best resources about English, in English"

Comment: I don't think this answer is to the question as put. I read the question about whether it is _the best resources to read [irrelevant] in_ or _the best resources to read [irrelevant] on_: it's whether you read in or on the resource, not about whethe the resource is in or on English.

Comment: @LifelongLearner More natural, I think, would be: *I want to share the best English resources on English.* Using English attributively means that it's written in English.

Comment: @AbuOmar You cannot end the sentence with either *in* or *on*. If that's what you were actually asking, then neither is grammatical.